# Move values duplicated between columns

Tags: vba, excel

1. This is my Excel sheet. Columns G and Column J have the same values but in different order.

[image]

2. The code runs and moves the values from Column J to Column H, beside the same value of column G.

[image]

3. The problem with this is that when there are two values the same it moves it to the first value it finds in Column H. The value `747.00` in J:2 must move to H:2 while the value `747.00` in J:5 must move to H:6 not to H:2.

[image]
[image]

This is the code:

```
Dim cel As Range, cel2 As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cel In Range(Cells(1, 7), Cells(lastRow, 7))
    For Each cel2 In Range(Cells(1, 10), Cells(lastRow, 10))
        If cel2.Value = cel.Value Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = cel2.Value
            cel2.Value = ""
        End If
    Next cel2
Next cel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are cycling through column J and looking for a match in column G. I've reversed that by cycling through column G and looking for a match in column J. Once one match has been found it is moved over to column H thereby removing it from column J.

```
Sub match_em_up()
    Dim rwg As Long, rwj As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For rwg = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
            If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Columns("J"), .Cells(rwg, "G").Value2)) Then
                rwj = Application.Match(.Cells(rwg, "G").Value2, .Columns("J"), 0)
                .Cells(rwg, "H") = .Cells(rwj, "J").Value2
                .Cells(rwj, "J").ClearContents
            End If
        Next rwg
    End With
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]